# Why can't I send eth to contract?

Tags: solidity

I am deploying a contract to Ganache.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.13;

contract Inbox {

    function getSenderBalance() public view returns (uint256) {
        return address(msg.sender).balance;
    }

    function sendEth(uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(address(msg.sender).balance >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        payable(address(this)).transfer(amount);
    }
}
```

In `sendEth` method, I expect the caller will transfer `amount` to the contract. The return value from `getSenderBalqance` is  `99999999999990743906`. I got below error when calling `sendEth`, I just passed `1` to the amount:

```
transact to Inbox.sendEth pending ... 
transact to Inbox.sendEth errored: VM error: revert.

revert
    The transaction has been reverted to the initial state.
Note: The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.
Debug the transaction to get more information.
```

Comment: Remove the `payable(address(this)).transfer(amount);` because while the function is already payable, and you send ether while calling it, you don't need to explicitly mention the transfer. And please stick to one ddiscussion thread for the same problem as @Torof mentioned

Answer (score 2):

This is a duplicate of **your previous question asked a few hours ago**. Please do not spam the forum.

You may be missing the basic concepts of Solidity. I would advise you to read the [official docs](https://soliditylang.org/)

If you want to send ether to a contract through a function you need to define this function as `payable` and simply forward ether with your transaction (`msg.value`)

In your function

```
function sendEth(uint256 amount) public payable {
        require(address(msg.sender).balance >= amount, "Insufficient balance");
        payable(address(this)).transfer(amount);
    }
```

you are actually telling **the contract to transfer ether to itself**.
To send ether you can forward ether with your function or simply send ether to the smart contract.

If you use [Remix IDE](https://remix.ethereum.org/) you can simulate the amount to forward with your function with the value tab :

[image]

Comment: I tried to put `1` on the `value` field when deploying the contract. But it gives me this error: `The called function should be payable if you send value and the value you send should be less than your current balance.` but the account I am using has 99 eths.

Comment: Do I have to do a deployment each time when I want to send eth to the contract? I thought I should be able to specify the amount via the contract method. As you said the code I have is to transfer ether to itself, what is the method I should use to transfer ether from caller to contract?

Answer (score 0):

just remove the last line from the contract

`payable(address(this)).transfer(amount);`

this is used when you want to transfer eth to other from the contract balance.

Comment: What is the method I can use to transfer from one account to another account?

Comment: Does it make sense if I change it to `payable(address(msg.sender)).transfer(amount);`?

Comment: The answer by @torof is better than this.